# Help Cleaning up a bit of Python Code

Tags: python, variables, tuples

Below i have a bit of code which assigns values based on the values within the tuple **tup**.
Now this bit of code is too repetitive for my tastes and i'd like to be able to use a loop with it.

Snippet:

```
    self.Levels = tup[0]
    self.MaxX   = tup[1]
    self.MaxY   = tup[2]
    self.BW     = tup[3]
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of the below; however, this obviously syntactically won't work in python.

```
    nametup = (self.Levels, self.MaxX, self.MaxY, self.BW)

    for i in range(len(tup)):
        nametup[i] = tup[i]
```

**EDIT:**

I've had to change my snippet to:

```
    if tup[0] != None:
        self.Levels = tup[0]

    if tup[1] != None:
        self.MaxX   = tup[1]

    if tup[2] != None:
        self.MaxY   = tup[2]

    if tup[3] != None:
        self.BW     = tup[3]
```

The if statement from what I understand throws a wrench into the unpacking the tuple idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the revised snippet:

```
attrs = ('Levels', 'MaxX', 'MaxY', 'BW')
assert len(tup) == len(attrs)
for attr, val in zip(attrs, tup):
    if val is not None: # don't use !=
        setattr(self, attr, val)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
self.Levels, self.MaxX, self.MaxY, self.BW = tup
```

It's called unpacking the tuple.

Comment: +1 ... and it doesn't sweep errors (like more than 4 elements in `tup`) under the carpet.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the long way 'round, but for comparison:

```
attrs = ('Levels', 'MaxX', 'MaxY', 'BW')
for attr,val in zip(attrs,tup):
    setattr(self, attr, val)
```